# Special Join Symbol

Tags: symbols

I tried to recreate this special join symbol, but couldn't get the short vertical line on the right side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\begin{document}
    
$e_{1} {\tiny\textifsym{|><|h|}}e_{2}$

\end{document}
```

What I got:

[image]

But I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just draw a hook after the standard join symbol (ifthis needs to work at other font sizes would need a bit extra work)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\zjoin{\mathbin{%
\bowtie\begin{picture}(0,0)(3.2,-2.8)
\put(0,2){\line(1,0){2}}
\put(2,2){\line(0,-1){2}}
\end{picture}}}

\begin{document}

$e_{1} \bowtie e_{2}$

$e_{1} \zjoin e_{2}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much.